# Bootstrap-Select width in form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-select

I'm using Bootstrap v4 and bootstrap-select js/css (in ASP.NET MVC project) and I have a problem in my `form`. The `select` with `multiple` options from `bootstrap-select` is wider than the rest of my `inputs`, even though it's in a `div` with `class="form-control"`.
The output looks something like this:
[image]

As you can see, the Field Of Expertise `dropdown` is way larger then the rest of the `inputs`. I tried to edit `bootstrap-select.css` and change `width:auto`, but didn't work. Is there anything I can do to match the `width` of my other `inputs`?

My code looks something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(v => v.BirthDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.BirthDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.BirthDate)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(v => v.ResidenceCountry)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.ResidenceCountry, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.ResidenceCountry)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrencyId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrencyId, new SelectList(Model.Currencies, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrencyId)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldOfExpertiseIds)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.FieldOfExpertiseIds, new MultiSelectList(Model.FieldOfExpertises, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", @data_selected_text_format = "count > 2", @data_size = "6" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FieldOfExpertiseIds)
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed now the form-group to something like this (added `@data_width = "auto"`):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldOfExpertiseIds)
    <br />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.FieldOfExpertiseIds, new MultiSelectList(Model.FieldOfExpertises, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", @data_selected_text_format = "count > 2", @data_size = "6" , @data_width="auto" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FieldOfExpertiseIds)
</div>
```

And now it looks a little bit better, but still a problem:
[image]

Comment: Not familiar with "selectpicker".  Does this come from a third party library?

Comment: Yes, https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it to work once I straightened out some external dependencies.  One thing to pay attention to is the versions required. JQuery 1.8.0+ and bootstrap version 4 didn't work for me. I was able to get it to work with 3.3.6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap.js@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="test0">test</label>
        <input id="test0" class="form-control" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="test1">drop down</label>
        <select id="test1" class="form-control" type="text">
          <option>One</option>
          <option>Two</option>
          <option>Three</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label >test 1</label>
        <select id="test2" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Check out the [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eUXwCIaM1E5AsO8yPttG?p=preview)

Answer (score 35):

You better try using **`data-width`** attribute to set the width of the select.

Set `data-width` to `auto` to **automatically adjust the width of the select to its widest option**. `fit` **automatically adjusts the width of the select to the width of its currently selected option**. An exact value can also be specified, e.g. `300px` or `50%.`

So I will suggest you to use something like this

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
  ...
</select>
```

So in your case better use - `data_width = "100%"` and if its wider, then change the width as per your need e.g., `75%` or `50%.`

**[Source link](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#width)**

I hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: when you put `-ve` please comment on the issue you faced so I can also understand the bug and fix it. It will also be helpful for others. ty

Comment: Thanks, it works, but your source link is broken, it should be  
[this][1]

  [1]: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#width

Comment: I have changed the link, glad my solution  solved your issue.